# Add a trigger on a column when I update its value very quickly

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I'm working with SQL Server 2012 Express edition and developer edition (with the latest Service Pack).

I have a table that will have a lot of rows, and I want to create a trigger in one of its columns. This trigger will be triggered when I update it (I will update only a row each time).

This is the table:

```
CODE | LEVEL | FLAG | More columns...
-----+-------+------+---------
```

I want to add a trigger on `FLAG` column. `CODE` and `LEVEL` are primary key. And the update will be: `UPDATE CODE SET FLAG = 1 WHERE CODE = N'ASD' AND LEVEL = 1;`

On that trigger I will need the value `updated` in column `FLAG`.

How can I do it?

Will be a problem if I update a lot rows on `CODE` table very quickly? (around 1200 rows in a minute)

If I update the rows very quickly, does a new trigger will wait until the previous trigger will be executed?

Comment: What is the primary key of your table?  You can join the CODE and inserted tables in the trigger to identify the updated rows, and add the additional criteria to the `WHERE` clause.  The trigger executes synchronously under the same context as the `UPDATE` statement that fired the trigger.  I wouldn't expect performance to be an issue due to joining on the primary key due to the unique primary key index.

Comment: As you can read on my question, CODE and LEVEL are primary key.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the composite primary key in you question.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a trigger example that joins to the inserted table to identify the updated rows and further qualifies the rows to be updated.  I wouldn't expect performance to be a concern due to joining on the primary key, which provides a unique index.

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_CODE_UPDATE
ON dbo.CODE FOR UPDATE AS

UPDATE c
SET FLAG = 1
FROM dbo.CODE AS c
JOIN inserted AS i ON
    i.CODE = c.CODE
    AND i.LEVEL = c.LEVEL
WHERE 
    c.CODE = N'ASD'
    AND c.LEVEL = 1;

GO
```